# Exploiting linux, scanf and reading permissions

Tags: c, linux, scanf, exploit

You might realise this looks like an assignement and for this reason, I’m just looking for cues and not necessarily complete solution.

TLDR: Is there a way to do command injection with `scanf` in C? And how to read a file which we don’t have the permission to read?

The goal is to open and read two files which will give access  to a third file. `file1`, `file2` and `file3`. The right for the file are as below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root source 40 1 Jan. 00:00 folder/file1
-rw-r----- 1 root source 40 1 Jan. 00:00 folder/file2
-rw-r----- 1 root source 40 1 Jan. 00:00 file3
drwxr-x--x 2 root source 4096 1 Jan. 00:00 folder
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root source 14376 1 Jan. 00:00 exe
```

We are in a folder `source` that contains `file3`, an executable `exe` and another folder that contains two files. The `exe` program shows the content of `file3` if we can access `file 1` and `file 2`. `file1` content is readable and thus we know that it’s content is pass1.

Thus, when we execute `exe`, we are presented with a prompt (which is a `scanf`, the program is in C).

Using `strace` , here is what we got:

```
read(0, pass1
"pass1\n", 1024)               = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/source1/folder/file1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "pass1", 6)                    = 6
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
// The next part only appear when we enter pass1 at the prompt
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/source1/folder/file2", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
read(4, 0x5636137c16c0, 16)             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

Here we see what I think is a sort of string comparaison, and when we get the pass1 right at the prompt, `exe` try to open the second file but doesn’t have the right to do so. There isn’t a second prompt before the tentative to open `file2`, so there isn’t the opportunity to enter a second pass to try to open `file2`, which we don’t have the permission to anyway.

My question is, is there a way to do command injection with a prompt `scanf`? And how to work around the fact that we have no permittion to read `file2`? Also is there a way that would make what we enter at the prompt different at the second read ( ex: pass1 at first read, and pass2 at second read because we entered pass1 & pass2 at the prompt?).

Comment: Assuming there is something like `scanf("%s", some_char_array)` without any limitation of the input string length you can try to enter many characters and look what happens. If you enter more characters than would fit into `some_char_array` it will overwrite whatever is in memory after this array.

Comment: I can't seem to overflow the buffer and cause a segmentation fault, is it because the scanf might be limiting the number of character possible. With the use of ltrace, the scanf prompt is ```scanf(0x5560e3f63768, 0x5560e4dd8260, 0x5560e4dd8260, 0x5560e4dd8260```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answering in comments. Describe what exactly you did and what happens. You won't necessarily get a segmentation fault on buffer overflow. This can happen but the behavior is undefined. To exploit the bug your goal is to overwrite some other data in a specific way without causing a segmentation fault. The difficulty is to find out how much and what data you have to pass. The program `exe` has the `setgid` bit set and belongs to the same group as the files, so the program can read files that are readable for group `source`.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you mean with "The exe program shows the content of `file3` **if we can access `file1` and `file2`**." If you run the program with `strace` as an unprivileged user, it will drop the `setgid` permission, so it cannot access `file2`. It may behave differently when you don't use `strace`.